# Integration of an trig function

Tags: calculus

How should i start off in integrating the below function. i am trying to use trig substitution? But i can't really see what to replace off in this case. any tips on how to start off with it?

$$\int\frac{1}{2+cosx}dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t=\tan{(x/2)}$; then $dx=2 \, dt/(1+t^2)$ and $\cos{x} = (1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$.  The integral is then

$$2\int \frac{dt}{3+t^2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan{\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}}+C=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan{\left [\frac{\tan{(x/2)}}{\sqrt{3}}\right ]}+C$$